# WebAPI. Dependency injection with Ninject in case of inheritance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm pretty new to **ASP.NET WebApi** project, but hopefully I'll put everything straight enough. After creating couple CRUD Controllers a brilliant idea come to my mind - write generic base CRUD-web-API controller for all of them and do not mess with rewriting same code.
After successful implementation of such class I faced problem with dependency resolving which is still working fine for non-generic/-inherited controllers. 

Simple request (GET, POST, etc.) gives:

**`Type 'UsersController' does not have a default constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"`**

Default constructor without injections works fine. Obviously I have a problem with Ninject configuration.

```
public abstract class BaseCRUDController<T> : ApiController where T : class, IClientEntity 
   {
      private readonly Repository<T> _repo;
      private readonly IDbContextDataProvider _context;

      // With this ctor everything works well
      public BaseCRUDController()
      {
         this._context = new ModelContext();
         this._repo = new Repository<T>(this._context);
      }

      // Injection is not working ((
      public BaseCRUDController(IDbContextDataProvider context)
      {
         this._context = context;
         this._repo = new Repository<T>(context);
      }
```

And concrete `Controller` for `User` entity:

```
public class UsersController : BaseCRUDController<User>
{      
  UsersController(IDbContextDataProvider context) : base(context) { }

  UsersController() : base() { }
}
```

And Ninject config itself:

```
public class DataProviderModule : NinjectModule
{
  public override void Load()
  {
     this.Bind<IDbContextDataProvider>().To<ModelContext>().InSingletonScope();
  }
}
public class NinjectResolver
{
  // Instantinate Ninject dependencies resolver
  public static System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver GetConfiguredDependencyResolver()
  {
     IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new DataProviderModule());
     System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver njResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);
     return njResolver;
  }
}
```

And `Application_Start`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    config.DependencyResolver = NinjectResolver.GetConfiguredDependencyResolver();

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

NOTE: This approach works well if I have:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{      
  UsersController(IDbContextDataProvider context)
  {
     .... 
  }    

...
```

Comment: Is it possible that the MVC resolver is being used, rather than the Web API dependency resolver?  I wonder if it is possible that the framework chooses the wrong resolver here because your controller doesn't derive immediately from  ApiController.  You could track this down through the stack trace -  I've come across a vaguely similar problem where this was the issue.

Comment: I have tried this out on a test project of mine and it works without issue.  It looks like I'm implementing Ninject a little different from how you're doing it.  I used a combination of [this](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/) and [this](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/) approach.

Comment: @BrianS Even with approach from link that you provided I have same result(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh.. I've spent hours trying different approaches. It was madness. And the funny part here is that `Ninject` is working well and code is correct except one accessibility modifier. Adding `public` modifier to `UsersController` ctor fixed the issue.

```
public class UsersController : BaseCRUDController<User>
{      
  public UsersController(IDbContextDataProvider context) : base(context) { }

...
```

*PS. Write your code carefully...*